# Missing Python file for models using pyCommunicator

Tags: anylogic

My experience with Python is limited, but I just started looking at the new Python models included AnyLogic's examples. I am looking at the 1st one Passing Data Types. The model runs correctly with the set, modify and get functions working as expected. My question is there a python file somewhere that the communicator is working with? I only see the .alp file in the folder.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm also beginning to use this, but as I understand, the idea of the python helper here (among other things) is that you can run python commands with Anylogic, so you actually don't need a python file. Nevertheless it uses python installed in your computer to run the scripts, if you don't have python installed, your model won't work.

Comment: It appears that it is both. If you look at the example model Running Python Files it allows interaction with .py file as well. This is an exciting addition to the AnyLogic capability. Thank you @Felipe for your input.

Comment: it is both, but you were asking for the passing data types example :P .. it would be dumb if you can run python commands but not run python scripts

Comment: I misunderstood passing data as something that would pass data from AnyLogic to a python file...but looking at this in the broader context it now makes sense.